# CakePHP: How to filter hasMany

Tags: cakephp

I have Event HABTM Category with categories_events table.
I want to display only Event with given `category_id`. So since I have catId I don't need to go till Category model. I could dynamically bind hasMany association from Event to Cat_Event.

How do I set find() second parameter array to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way from EventsController:

```
$this->Event->Category->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Category.id' => $catid)
));
```